# cx_Oracle and ODPI-C configuration

Tags: python, sql, cx-oracle

I'm trying to get Oracle's cx_Oracle module running so I can run sql queries to an Oracle database from within Python. I'm having a tough time with the installation.

I originally used conda to install cx_Oracle. From what I can tell cx_Oracle needs odpi-c and Oracle Instant Client installed to work. I installed those into the file where most of my other packages are stored and then used sys.path.append() to add them. When I do that I still get the error DPI-1047:

> DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

The problem seems to be with ODPI-C? The referred to documentation provides very little detail on how to configure the Oracle software. Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the Oracle Client libraries.  ODPI-C is already included in cx_Oracle.  Python cx_Oracle installation instructions are [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows).  Make sure you have the 64-bit Oracle libraries, not the 32-bit libraries.